# How to count the lines in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, and I would count the lines which appear in 10 "event_id" column.

I have this code, but doesnt work...

```
SELECT COUNT(event_id) FROM wp_leagueengine_season_matches_events, wp_leagueengine_tournament_matches_attributes WHERE event_id = '10'
```

Comment: You need to count both tables separately, OR JOIN them on some matching column(s). You can't reference `event_id` without the table it belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this

```
SELECT COUNT(wpe.event_id) as nr_wpe, COUNT(wpa.event_id) as nr_wpa  
FROM wp_leagueengine_season_matches_events wpe
INNER JOIN wp_leagueengine_tournament_matches_attributes wpa
    ON nr=nr_wpe+nr_wpa
WHERE event_id = 10
```